# Print role name of the caller role in Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-role

How to print caller role name from within another role?

Playbook:

```yaml
- name: print calling role name
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - import_role:
        name: role2
        tasks_from: update
```

*role2/tasks/update.yml:*

```yaml
- name: role 2
  import_role:
    name: role1
    tasks_from: update
  vars:
    role_scope: "{{ role_name }}"
```

*role1/tasks/update.yml:*

```yaml
- name: role 1
  debug:
    msg: "Calling role: {{ role_scope }}"
```

*Current output*

```
Calling role: role1
```

*Expected output*

```
Calling role: role2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed in the [special variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html) page, there is a variable `ansible_parent_role_names` that contains a list of all the ancestor roles.

> When the current role is being executed by means of an [include_role](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_role_module.html#include-role-module) or [import_role](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/import_role_module.html#import-role-module) action, this variable contains a list of all parent roles, with the most recent role (in other words, the role that included/imported this role) being the first item in the list. When multiple inclusions occur, this list lists the last role (in other words, the role that included this role) as the first item in the list. It is also possible that a specific role exists more than once in this list.
>
> For example: When role **A** includes role **B**, inside role B, `ansible_parent_role_names` will equal to `['A']`. If role **B** then includes role **C**, the list becomes `['B', 'A']`.

So, the solution is to use it in `role1`:

```yaml
- name: role 1
  debug:
    msg: "Calling role: {{ ansible_parent_role_names[0] }}"
```

---

And if you want it to work whatever it is called by another role or not, you could do:

```yaml
- name: role 1
  debug:
    msg: >-
      Calling role: {{ ansible_parent_role_names[0] | default(role_name) }}
```

This way, it will answer

```
Calling role: role2
```

When called via `role2`, but

```
Calling role: role1
```

when calling `role1` directly in the playbook, for example.